# glTexImage2D reads out of bounds

Tags: opengl, textures

I am trying to read data into a texture with glTexImage2D.
It seems like no matter what I try, the first row of texels is read correctly, but further rows are created from memory way beyond the boundaries of the given std::vector:

```
GLuint renderedTexture;
glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);

int w = 8;
int h = 8;
std::vector<GLuint> emptyData(w*h, 0);

emptyData[0] = 0xFF<<8; //blue
emptyData[1] = 0xFF<<16; //green
emptyData[3] = 0xFF<<24; //red
emptyData[w] = 0xFF<<16; // <- should be in second row, but is not shown

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, w, h, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8, emptyData.data());
```

Depending on the size of the texture the code segfaults. I have already tried using a vector of GLubytes, but that didn't work either. I have also tried `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)`, but that didn't work either. What am I missing here?

Edit: Further experimenting revealed that the minimum width assumed when reading in pixels seems to be 128px. So if I create a texture of size 64*64 and want a single pixel at x = 10, y = 14, I have to write into `emptyData[10 + 14*128]` and have to reserve the appropriate amount of memory beforehand. Does someone know if this is platform dependant or why this is?

Comment: `w*h*4` in the vector constructor. You want 4 bytes per pixel, but you're allocating only 1.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I don't think that's correct. Index 0 of the vector relates to the first pixel and index 1 relates to the second pixel, as I am using `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8`. Even if I use `w*h*4` I still get uninitialized pixels in my texture.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz The type is `GLuint` which is 32 bit data type!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading your observation of the minimal line width, the `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH` pixel storage mode comes to mind (see [OpenGL-Refpage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml)).

It allows you to set the size of row, skipping line padding or other data between rows. However by default this should be zero. Maybe the `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH` is set somewhere else in your code?

Comment: That would be my guess as well.

Comment: You are right, setting it to 0 indeed fixes the problems. However, I did not set it to anything other than zero. My guess would be that SDL is setting that value (which I use to create the window etc.) to 128 without mentioning it in the documentation...